# Creating multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Currently, I have this piece of code to create a numpy array

```
X=np.array([[]]);

if (X.shape[1] == 0):
      X = np.array([vd]);
    else:
      X = np.concatenate((X,np.array([vd])));
```

I would now like to get multiple numpy arrays X(1) , X(2) etc for different conditions. What is the best way to do this in python. In matlab I can accomplish this using matlab struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see @user3510686 has already answered it. Posing what I tried.

```
a={}
for i in range(10):
    a[i]=np.random.rand(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a python dictionary for this purpose
For example

```
import numpy as np
dic={}
dic['1']=np.zeros(3)
dic['2']=np.ones(5)
print dic['1']
print dic['2']
```

now dic['1'] and dic['2'] are you arrays

Comment: can it be dic[1]=np.zeros(3) ?

Comment: Yes, it can be like that as well